# Fan fiction about Peter Parker getting kidnapped on the way to a camp thing and being experimented on for around 4 days

Tags: story-identification, marvel, spider-man, iron-man, fan-fiction

Tony Stark and Natasha Romanova find Peter. He’s got pods implanted in his arms that hurt him if moves them. He’s got special handcuffs on. He’s had to leave supervised phone messages for his Aunt May to keep anyone from knowing he’s actually missing. Manages to sneak in a few clues before he’s caught. Tony and Natasha are the ones who save him I think... they find him with an IV in his neck and leaning against the wall. He doesn’t think they are real at first, just hallucinations.

I can’t remember where I read it but most likely AO3 or Fanfiction.net are the two most likely.

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly which story you are talking about. I can't find it at the moment. However, I know that it was based off of Chapter Six of grilledcheesing's "5 Times Peter Made Tony Laugh Out Loud". Basically, [this chapter](https://archiveofourown.org/works/11592432/chapters/26392224) served as inspiration for that story. The one you're talking about is an expanded, and slightly darker version of that chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I was beginning to think I imagined the story or something. Lol. I’ve tried searching for it using all sorts of combinations of key words to no effect. 

Comment: I tried searching for it using the quotes from the linked story - it used it as a building block, so I know the messages were used word for word. Since I didn't find anything, I think it might have been taken down. (Also, I'm not sure, but I think I read it because it was linked directly. Since even that's not there, I think that's another sign it was taken down.)

Comment: Well that just sucks.  I think you’re  right about it being taken down...unfortunately.